# lightGallery not loading images

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, lightgallery

The page I am experiencing this issue on is [this one.](http://abbagoldeurope.com/gallery/)

I have tried swapping out static lightGallery JS for CDNJS version, I've tried calling the function in both JS and jQuery and I've even tried calling the lightGallery JS in both the header and footer but I'm still getting this issue.

I've tried searching but can't find any questions with a relevant and working answer for me.

I've had this plug in working in the past but it seems to have broken over the weekend. I thought it might have been a WordPress update that's broken it but I can't roll back to check!

Code example below:

```js
$("#isotope-list").lightGallery();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightgallery/1.3.9/js/lightgallery.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightgallery/1.3.9/css/lightgallery.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<ul id="isotope-list" class="small-block-grid medium-block-grid large-block-grid">

  <li class="ghentenaar item lazy" data-original="http://abbagoldeurope.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/ghent46-e1421310997505.jpg" height="150px" width="150px">
    <div class="gallery-inner">
      <img class="th" src="http://abbagoldeurope.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/ghent46-150x150.jpg" />
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="ghentenaar item lazy" data-original="http://abbagoldeurope.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/ghent12-e1421311015711.jpg" height="150px" width="150px">
    <div class="gallery-inner">
      <img class="th" src="http://abbagoldeurope.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/ghent12-150x150.jpg" />
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="ghentenaar item lazy" data-original="http://abbagoldeurope.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/ghent11-e1421311034730.jpg" height="150px" width="150px">
    <div class="gallery-inner">
      <img class="th" src="http://abbagoldeurope.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/ghent11-150x150.jpg" />
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

```
<ul id="isotope-list" class="small-block-grid medium-block-grid large-block-grid" style="position: relative; height: 0px;">


<li data-src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AW63bqMYkF4">
    <img src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/AW63bqMYkF4/default.jpg">
</li>


<li data-src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JBzTx_3L57w">
    <img src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/JBzTx_3L57w/default.jpg">
</li>


<li data-src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F6LpkwQe_RA">
    <img src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/F6LpkwQe_RA/default.jpg">
</li>                           
</ul>
```

The error I get in console is `TypeError: src is undefined`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The full content of your question must be **in** your question, not just linked. Links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future, and people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you. Put a [mcve] **in** the question, ideally using Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button) to make it runnable. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: The snippet doesn't demonstrate the problem ("verifiable"). With respect, it also fell down pretty badly on the "minimal" part -- we don't need 400 lines of items with pictures in them, just a few will do. I removed most of them (probably not enough).

Comment: my question, do you use video as part of the slideshow?

Comment: @iMarkDesigns Not on that page, but there is a page with a video gallery - the videos are hosted on youtube (also not working)

Comment: Do you follow the embed format that lightgallery required? that was what i can see on if that was your case...

Update: check this mark `var youtube = src.match(/\/\/(?:www\.)?youtu(?:\.be|be\.com)\/(?:watch\?v=|embed\/)?([a-z0-9\-\_\%]+)/i);`

Update 2: First i can see this error: `$(document).ready(function({$("li.lazy").lazyload();});`

Comment: @iMarkDesigns The video and images have been working fine for a while now. Over the weekend, I received an email form the site owner telling me they had stopped working. When I first installed the plugin, I copy/pasted the base code for the images and videos and then built up around that so it should be fine? I've updated the question with a copy of the HTML code form the Videos page.

Comment: @E.Owen i see... im trying to dig down more about errors from Inspect Elements to see what exactly causing your issue. If you can debug your script codes again one by one, maybe you can see the issue there.

Comment: @E.Owen For the video, i thnk, you should use the embed one. Something like this: `https://www.youtube.com/embed/o7WYpYGhmzA`

Comment: @iMarkDesigns I've just updated those links on the live site -  unfortunately didn't fix the issue... I'm no longer getting any errors in the console though... ignore that. I'm still getting the src error.

Comment: one last thing, `$(document).ready(function({$("li.lazy").lazyload();});` if you do minimize this manually, you should remove the ";" after `lazyload()`.

Comment: @iMarkDesigns Thanks for your help so far. I've edited the lazy load call but that error still seems to be appearing. I'm still getting the lightGallery Type Error, too. Strange that it was working fine for some months and now it's all of a sudden stopped working. As far as I'm aware, nothing changed before I started editing  the files today.

Comment: Ok. i feel you. especially when im using photoswipe similar to lightgallery. I hope you can find solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine, the only problem is you doesn't have the lightgallery video plugin.

you should call all of JS included in the lightgallery stuff to get every feature working:

```
<script src="js/lightgallery/lightgallery.js"></script>
<script src="js/lightgallery/lg-fullscreen.js"></script>
<script src="js/lightgallery/lg-thumbnail.js"></script>
<script src="js/lightgallery/lg-video.js"></script>
<script src="js/lightgallery/lg-autoplay.js"></script>
<script src="js/lightgallery/lg-zoom.js"></script>
<script src="js/lightgallery/lg-hash.js"></script>
<script src="js/lightgallery/lg-pager.js"></script>
```

This is an example with video plugin added: https://jsfiddle.net/4Lkuwcga/

Comment: Do I need to include every file, even if I'm not using all of the features? I'm concerned about increasing page load speed if I don't necessarily _need_ to...

Comment: in your case, just call the video plugin, ive added in my jsfiddle example and it works with that feature

Comment: I've found that this works for the videos but not the pictures. I'm currently loading every javascript file included with light gallery and the site is running extremely slowly! Any further suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: are you calling the js files form external domains? like `src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.......` ? if you are doing that, you should download the files and calling them from the same website `src="myfolder/js/.......`

Comment: I've tried both but it's still not working! I haven't yet tried loading everything in using files local to the site though. I'll try that next and see where it gets me.

Comment: maybe theres another problem, i recommend you to check in the element inspector (network tab) to check which thing is causing the slow loading